# How i turn like 1592.50 into 1593 with php?

Tags: php

i want a way to check if the number has comma, then it return it into the next number.

example :

```
<?
    $mynum = "6265.50";
    // output : 6266 , and not 6,266 like the function of number_format()
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `round();` or `ceil()` to round up fractions.

Comment: It's worth noting that the default behavior of `round()` is to round up.  Rounding can be modified, however, by changing the third parameter to one of `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP`, `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN`, `PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN`, or `PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD`.

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the [`ceil`](http://php.net/ceil) function :

```
$mynum = "6265.50";
echo ceil($mynum);
```

will give you :

```
6266
```

Answer (score 3):

use `ceil($mynum)`

Answer (score 3):

`echo ceil(6265.50);`